# Camel filter - invoking different beans with proxy

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to invoke a different service depending on the bean input. But my instance service is not getting invoked. Please find the code below:

My Route

```
    from("jms:queue:instance").filter()
            .method(instanceTypeFilter, "isMCUInstance")
            .to("instanceservice").filter()
            .method(instanceTypeFilter, "isDMAInstance")
            .to("instanceservice").filter()
            .method(instanceTypeFilter, "isWSPInstance")
            .to("instanceservice").filter()
            .method(instanceTypeFilter, "isMEAInstance")
            .to("instanceservice").filter()
            .method(instanceTypeFilter, "isRSSInstance")
            .to("instanceservice");
```

Below method calls is getting invoked

```
public class InstanceTypeFilter {
public boolean isMCUInstance(Instance instance) {
    System.out.println("Entering : InstanceTypeFilter : isMCUInstance");
    System.out.println("instance.getType() : " + instance.getType());
    return instance.getType() == "MCU";


 ......................

}
```

But below code is not getting invoked

```
   Service(value = "instanceservice")
   public class InstanceServiceImpl implements InstanceService {

public Instance add(final Instance instance) {
    System.out.println("Entering : InstanceServiceImpl : add");
    instance.setId("newId");
    instance.setName("newName");
    instance.setType("newType");
    System.out.println("Exiting : InstanceServiceImpl : add");
    return instance;
}

}
```

I am a bigginner to Camel, as for as i understood, add method should get executed. I am using proxy with spring remoting for invoking add method.

I tried like below, but still the problem persists

```
  .when(method(InstanceTypeFilter.class, "isMCUInstance")
                    .isEqualTo(true))
            .to("instanceservice")
            .when(method(InstanceTypeFilter.class, "isDMAInstance")
                    .isEqualTo(true))
            .to("instanceservice")
            .when(method(InstanceTypeFilter.class, "isWSPInstance")
                    .isEqualTo(true))
            .to("instanceservice")
            .when(method(InstanceTypeFilter.class, "isMEAInstance")
                    .isEqualTo(true))
            .to("instanceservice")
            .when(method(InstanceTypeFilter.class, "isRSSInstance")
                    .isEqualTo(true)).to("instanceservice");
```

Comment: It's not getting invoked because your filters are filtering it out! That's what a filter is designed to do. Claus's answer describes how to use `choice()` `when()` ... `end()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the content based router instead of the filter eip

The EIPs is listed here with examples
http://camel.apache.org/eip

The EIP you are looking for is here
http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html

The content based router is just like a if .. else if .. else if ... else control structure in any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.to("instanceservice")` try using `.to("bean:instanceservice?method=add")` or `.beanRef("instanceservice", "add")`;